# reading graph from titan using python without rexter server

Tags: python, graph, hbase, titan

I am working on python and needs to read data(need to know available available vertices, relationships between them and properties of each vertex) in Titan Graph database(may be in to excel for some understanding or analysis). I read through bulbs(http://bulbflow.com/docs/)but not able to use it. I only have below info.

1. Graph db titan uses hbase as backend storage.
2. It is in cluster with hostname: example-titan.com
3. Table name is "alphausers".
4. No Rexter server is used in creating graph.

Bulbs requires url to connect to graph db and i didn't understand how to pass hbase and table/graph name to access it. OR I am not using the correct library to access titan graph.

Comment: Unless you are implementing your own client to connect to titan directly I think you need to use Rexster for Titan: http://bulbflow.com/download/#get-neo4j-server-or-rexster

Comment: Thanks Marco. Using Java we can create graph in titan without rexster. There is no such python client?

Comment: All the clients they mention are using Rexster (both bulbs and thunderdome)

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @MarcoCI is correct.  For bulbs to work you need Rexster.  In fact all non-jvm clients require Rexster to connect to Titan.  Titan itself adopts Rexster communication protocols to make it language agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment:

> Unless you are implementing your own client to connect to titan directly I think you need to use Rexster for Titan: http://www.bulbflow.com/download/#get-neo4j-server-or-rexster